# How can I use firebug to debug javascript ran using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: asp.net, firebug

Since these scripts aren't loaded on the page in advance, how can I set breakpoints in them to watch what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering your question but you should avoid putting complex javascript in your codebehind and not mix client and server languages. At best you should limit yourself to a function call on the server but the actual implementation will be inside a separate javascript function inside a separate javascript file. This way not only that you will reduce the traffic between the client and the server on each AJAX call but your scripts will be cached:

```
SomeModelToPassToTheFunction model = ...
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);
var script = string.Format("someFunction({0});", json);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "somekey", script, true);
```

Oh, and now you can place breakpoints inside the function.

Comment: I don't have anything complex in the codebehind; but the function I want to debug into is called in numerous places and I'd like to be able to set a breakpoint that was only called from a single execution path.  I asked this hoping there was a less kludgy method than changing the initial call to `DebugKludge();` and then putting `function DebugKludge() { FunctionIWantToDebug(); }` into the .js just to make tracking down the problem easier.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in your sample code that's not in what I'm working with; but when I try and search on objectName.functionName() the only location I'm finding is an ~14k character line that has a bunch of other javascript splatted at the end of a huge mass of gibberish.  With all the other stuff there any breakpoint would probably be equally buried in false positives.